# Issue with HttpURLConnection on Android Nexus v4.0.2

Tags: android

The below code simply is not working on my Android Galaxy Nexus running v4.0.2 it works in the emulator and other older devices. When running on older devices and the emu the variable "is" is getting all the bytes as needed and all is good. While running on the Nexus it throws the file not found exception at "is" and "is" stays null. Then when I try to work with "is" further down the class it throws a null pointer because "is" is null. How can I fix this file not found error? The file is reachable on other devices/emu/browser.

I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: at is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

Here is the code:

```
// GET
InputStream is = null;
    try {
        // set the URL that points to a file to be downloaded
        URL url = new URL(downloadURL);

        // create the new connection
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        // set up some things on the connection
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        // connect and download
        urlConnection.connect();

        // used in reading the data from the internet
        is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Very interesting. when calling setDoOutput() it should be false instead of true. Changing this seemed to have fixed the problem. Question is why was this only affecting this device/os and not every other device/os? Hmmm

Comment: Had the same behaviour, but how exactly setDoOutput influences and produces in the end the io exception isn't clear to me. The method was called with true, even a request body was not sent. Change to false solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

Should be:

urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);

Answer (score 0):

`urlConnection.setDoOutput(true)` effectively changes the method to POST, so probably your server doesn't respond to POST?

`HTTPUrlConnection` has an ugly and confusing interface indeed. Here's a recent writeup on its peculiarities: 
 http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection

Comment: But if that would be the reason, why it works on older android versions, and not on v4. It seems to be a problem on the client.

Comment: Maybe a bug got fixed or a new one introduced. If you can pinpoint two particular versions, it's not that hard to do a diff.